# Display JQuery Validation errors on custom divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" class="form-horizontal" id="form-registrazione">
          <fieldset>
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h3 id="registrazioneLabel">Registrazione</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="control-group">
                      <!-- Username -->
                      <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                          <input name="username" class="span2" placeholder="Leonardo" id="username" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div id="username_msg"></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>



                <div class="control-group">
                      <!-- Email -->
                      <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                          <input name="email" class="span2" placeholder="mario@rossi.com" id="email" type="email">
                        </div>
                        <div id="email_msg"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                      <!-- Password -->
                      <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-key"></i></span>
                          <input name="password" class="span2" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password">
                        </div>
                        <div id="password_msg"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Conferma password -->
                  <label class="control-label">Conferma password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-key"></i></span>
                      <input name="repassword" class="span2" placeholder="Password" id="repassword" type="password">
                    </div>
                    <div id="repassword_msg"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrati" class="btn btn-primary">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Chiudi</button>
              </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

And the following Javascript Validation code:

```
<script>
    // SI ACCETTANO SOLO USERNAME CON CARATTERI ALFANUMERICI, SPAZI, TRATTINI E UDNERSCORE
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
        var stringa = new String(value);
        stringa = stringa.replace(" ", "");
        stringa = stringa.replace("-", "");
        stringa = stringa.replace("_", "");
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(stringa.valueOf());
    });

    // SCRIPT CHE CONVALIDA IL FORM DI REGISTRAZIONE
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form-registrazione').validate({
        rules: {
          username: {
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 15,
            alphanumeric: true,
            // L'USERNAME NON DEVE ESSERE GIA' USATO
            remote: {
                url: "do_action.php?action=username_used",
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                data: {
                  email: function() {
                    return $("#username").val();
                  }
                }
            },
            required: true
          },
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            // L'EMAIL NON DEVE ESSERE GIA' UTILIZZATA
            remote: {
                url: "do_action.php?action=email_used",
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                data: {
                  username: function() {
                    return $("#email").val();
                  }
                }
            },
          },
          password: {
            minlength: 8,
            required: true
          },
          repassword: {
            minlength: 8,
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#password"
          }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Scegli il tuo nome utente.",
                minlength: "Inserisci almeno almeno 6 caratteri.",
                maxlength: "Inserisci meno di 15 caratteri.",
                alphanumeric: "Si accettano soltanto caratteri alfanumerici, spazi, trattini e underscore.",
                remote: "L'username &egrave; gi&agrave; utilizzato da un altro giocatore, per favore scegline un altro."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Imposta una password.",
                minlength: "La password deve essere lunga almeno 8 caratteri.",
            },
            repassword: {
                required: "Conferma la tua password.",
                minlength: "La password deve essere lunga almeno 8 caratteri.",
                equalTo: "Le due password non combaciano."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Inserisci un indirizzo email.",
                email: "L'indirizzo email inserito non &egrave; corretto.",
                remote: "L'email &egrave; gi&agrave; utilizzata da un altro giocatore, puoi utilizzare un'altra email oppure <a href='recover.php'>recuperare i dati del tuo account</a>."
            }
        },
        highlight: function(label) {
            $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass("success").addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label
                .addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

The code works, it also checks if username/email are already used. The problem is that if the error string is too long the text goes out of the page (no new lines), so I created four divs in which I would like to place the error messages so the text will make new lines when needed.

My goal is to display every username error in the div "#username_msg", every email error in the div "#email_msg", etc. I tried many things, I searched and Google, I also tried the showErrors method but I couldn't fix my problem... so here I am.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and the form is displayed correctly into a Modal (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removed `[jquery-validation-engine]` tag since that's a whole different plugin.  Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Quote**:  "My goal is to display every username error in the div `#username_msg`,
>   every email error in the div `#email_msg`, etc.

You cannot put each individual message within their own uniquely tagged `div`.  You can, however, put the messages inside of a `div` element instead of a `label`.  However, this  will not solve your issue any better than simply using CSS to format the `label` element.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

> **errorElement**, String, Default: "label"
>
> Use this element type to create error messages and to look for
>   existing error messages. The default, "label", has the advantage of
>   creating a meaningful link between error message and invalid field
>   using the for attribute (which is always used, no matter the element
>   type).

As per comments, using `div` since the OP wants the message to display *under* the `input` element.

```
errorElement: "div"
```

Then you can control how the `div` displays using CSS...

```
div.error {
    width: 200px; // whatever you need
    white-space: normal;  // to ensure wrapping despite twitter bootstrap css
}
```

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/f9Ut4/1/

---

**EDIT:**

Explanation - there was a rule, `white-space: nowrap`, within the Twitter Bootstrap CSS file that was inherited by your `div.error` which told its text content to not wrap. The rule I suggest above, `white-space: normal`, simply reverses the `nowrap` rule and since it has a *more specific* target, `div.error`, it will take *precedence* over the rule within the Twitter Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I don't like the result plus I get a horizontal sidebar. I would like just to show the error messages under the text areas but without the text going out of the modal, just like if I write anything in the #username_msg div. Is there a way/CSS to do it?

Comment: @TheTux94, the text wraps and there is no horizontal sidebar in my jsFiddle demo.  What browser do you see this in?  Also, my answer is a demonstration about how you can finely control your own error labels, so feel free to make adjustments as needed.

Comment: @TheTux94, I updated my answer just now.  I use `div` which automatically goes underneath the input.  I also made it the same width as the input and the text should wrap with no scrollbars.  See the new demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f9Ut4/

Comment: Works on your website but not on mine. I probably miss something (I'm new to Javascript and CSS). The result on your last jsFiddle is the one I want to get. Probably there is some modal problem? Could you check my website, please? http://th3tux94.altervista.org/poly/index.php

Comment: @TheTux94, I don't see a problem on your website either.  However, using the DOM inspector I see this rule within your `bootstrap.min.css` - `.input-append, .input-prepend {
font-size: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}` ~ The `white-space: nowrap;` part is most likely causing the wrap to get botched in your browser.

Comment: @TheTux94, add `white-space: normal;` to your css for the error `div`.  See my edit above.

Comment: OMG You're a CSS master! I have no idea what was wrong and what changed but now it works! Thanks a lot! Maybe you could explain me what was wrong?

Comment: @TheTux94, there was a rule, `white-space: nowrap`, within your Twitter Bootstrap CSS that told the text in your `div` not to wrap.  The rule I suggest above has a _more specific_ target, `div.error`, so that it will take precedence over the Bootstrap CSS.  I used the DOM inspection tools built into the browser to find it.  Please don't forget to vote and "accept" my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I wasted an entire day on this problem. I think I would've never found a solution alone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving max-width to your div which prints error. So if the error string is huge they will automatically wrap them into new line

Comment: I use Twitter Bootstrap so the divs use a grid layout automatically.

Comment: In anycase you, you can still get the ID of the div. When all your validations are done using jQuery set the size of the div

$('#div-id').css('width','250');

Comment: I think I didn't understand. Could you give me a glimpse of the code? What is the div that shows the error?

Comment: I changed the code inside the "highlight" block to     $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass("success").addClass('error').css('width','400'); but all I get is a horizontal scrollbar :(.

Comment: may be your style sheet is getting over-written..make it !important  as..... css('width', '400 !important');